# Why do I get an 'invalid call' error when creating an R8G8B8 volume texture?

Tags: textures, sharpdx

I'm trying to create a `VolumeTexture` in C# with SharpDX, but it fails:

```
var form = new RenderForm("SharpDX - Test");
var device = new Device(new Direct3D(), 0, DeviceType.Hardware, form.Handle, CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, new PresentParameters(form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height));

VolumeTexture texture = new VolumeTexture(device, 4, 4, 4, 1, Usage.None, Format.R8G8B8, Pool.Managed);
```

The error is:

```
HRESULT: [0x8876086C], Module: [SharpDX.Direct3D9], ApiCode: [D3DERR_INVALIDCALL/InvalidCall], Message: Unknown
```

I searched but found no sample for volume textures in .NET; why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: "InvalidCall" generally means some parameter to the call was invalid. Have you enabled to D3D9 debug runtimes? It will usually cause additional diagnostics to be printed to your output window.

Comment: Are you sure `R8G8B8` is a supported volume format in SharpDX?  It's not in D3D - you have to use `R8G8B8A8`.

Comment: You're right. I tried it with "A8R8G8B8" and it works.